# We cannot reach branch.io in China

Tags: branch.io, great-firewall-of-china

It appears since this morning that we are unable to access branch.io links from China.

Is anyone else having issues? This has huge impact for us, we need to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring your network before you check the requests rejected by gfwlist. You can set a global VPN to access the

> https://branch.io

for test, I am now in China can access the URL normally, and after I faked a USA's IP, I can also visit the website.

**While if you just set a global VPN then access the website, maybe this site has been protected by GFW Recently.**

If that, I don't know why and most of the Chinese developers don't know why yet.

Comment: It seems to suffer from blocking in random ways. For 20 minutes this morning we could access with a VPN but not without VPN, and then it was back. This happened again a couple of minutes ago, nothing was accessible without a VPN for about 10 minutes.

Comment: At the time of this writing it's happening again. Neither the Dashboard or the branch.io links can be accessed without a VPN / Proxy.

Comment: @FlorianMonfort I hope you friend not rejected by gfw, I am not very sure you were blocked, but maybe of that. This year, our network env. strictly cut off from abroad for protecting mainland citizens by our governors compared with these years they done. The same time, abroads IP visiting also affected and limited.